# create radio button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table built from a DB.  It has a "Edit" button that will open up a form.

One of those input types will be a radio button I want to generate with On/Off selection:

```
<input type="radio" name="camera_status" value="On" /> On<br />
<input type="radio" name="camera_status" value="Off" /> Off
```

I have 3 problems:

1. I don't know how to create multiple radio options. The code below only creates one.
2. How do I make the value I passed in "camerastatus" the default checked value?
3. I need to have multiple labels. The form will be "Camera status" then labels for On/Off.

Code:

```
function edit2(to, cameraname, cameraquality, camerastatus, emailnotice, camerahash)
{
   var mydiv = document.getElementById("editform");
   var myForm = document.createElement("form");
   myForm.method = "post";
   myForm.action = to;

   //camera_status
   label = document.createElement("label");
   label.for = "text";
   label.innerHTML="<br>Camera status: <br>";
   myForm.appendChild(label);

   var myRadioElement;
   try{
      myRadioElement = document.createElement('<input type="radio" name="camera_status" />On');
   }catch(err){
      myRadioElement = document.createElement('input');
   }

   myRadioElement.type = "radio";
   myRadioElement.name = "camera_status";

   myForm.appendChild(myRadioElement);

   mydiv.appendChild(myForm);
}
```

Comment: _"I don't know how to create multiple radio options. The code below only creates one."_ - So take the bit that creates one and repeat it. Also, get rid of the try/catch and just do it the way you've got in the catch (along with the two lines after the end of the catch block). But wouldn't a checkbox be better suited to an on/off field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a radio button the default, add the checked attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="..." checked />
```

Wouldn't it be better to use a checkbox for something that can be on or off?

```
<input type="checkbox" ... />
```

Comment: Hrmm, a checkbox might be better.  I guess I wasn't clear.  It is pretty obvious how to do that in html.  I want to create the form with the radio (or checkbox) in javascript.

Comment: `myRadioElement.checked = true;`

Comment: that doesn't really help as I need multiple labels and it needs to be done in javascript...but you covered everything else.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

"Male" value is checked:

```
<div><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" checked="checked" /> Male</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" checked="" /> Female</div>
```

To do this in JavaScript you could just put a block of code where you needed the radio buttons, and use document.write with a for loop for each radio button you need. (You'll also want to change the value every time too, of course.)

-Neil